# How do I get Windows 10 Search into a working state?

Tags: windows, windows-10, search

I've been testing out build 1709 for potential deployment into our environment and have yet to get Windows Search to actually function properly.

In particular it seems to be having difficulty finding programs which are installed and showing on Apps & Features. I've disabled web searches, as shown below, however that doesn't seem to have fixed the issue.

Searches for stock programs, like Calculator, work fine.

[Group Policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qD9Ef.png)

[Windows Program List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtAV3.png)

[Search Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suWyr.png)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows 10 1709 machine, after install WinSCP and configure group policies, gpupdate/force, I can see WinSCP in search result.

[image]

Try to reinstall WinSCP and run search troubleshooter.